# Examples of metric in maplesoft

Tags: metric-spaces, maple

In the maplesoft website there are examples of metric and killing vectors. What are the name and significance of those geometries ?

https://de.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=DifferentialGeometry/Tensor/KillingVectors#examples